# "Happy for you are improving"—grammatically correct?

Tags: word-choice, phrases

Is it correct to say *I am happy for you are improving!* or does it necessarily have to be with **that**, as in here: *I am happy that you are improving!* ?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! Please wait at least a couple of days before selecting an answer. You may get an even better or more helpful one. People may not want to answer your question though, if you have already selected an answer. They may not bother to read it either.

Comment: One day is usually enough, if there aren't any new (different) answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first could be correct if *for* means *because*, but it needs a comma.

> I am happy, for [because] you are improving.

The second is also correct - it has a subtly different meaning but they are essentially the same.

Answer (score 1):

Your first sentence is perfectly fine but if you add a comma, it would reduce slight confusion.

> I am happy, for you are improving!

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is not correct. It can be corrected as such:
I am happy that you are improving
OR you need to add a comma or pause while speaking after "happy":
I am happy, for you are improving (for means because)